# Adding Missing text on bulk CSV file

Tags: csv

I have a large data set, roughly 7000 lines. this has been generated with a particular piece missing. Is there a way I can on mass add in the missing information? Below is an example line from my dataset,

PRIPOS;20150527;EUR;AAAAA;Maxi Dresses;5050300000000;22200000;Thyme;Thyme;6;**32**;AAAAAA MAXI DRESS;AAAAAA MAXI DRESS;2;All AAAAA Products;000;Dresses;100;Maxi Dresses;10000;Soft Maxi Dress;000.00;00.00;;;;;SS15;;;***Insert***;;

The first bold field (32) need to be considered the second bold field (insert) is where data needs to be added. The 32 represents a size and the Insert should represent a different size. file contains around 7k lines, all different information.

Is there a particular text editor that will allow me to use a wildcard on a replace function, or an ideas on a script? Failing this I would assume dumping into a SQL table and updating via query would be the quickest method?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What OS are you using?  Is the data shown above really one continuous line with no line breaks embedded within? when you say the 32 needs to be considered do you mean if that field is 32 then the insert text will be 'abc', if it's 33 then insert will be 'xyz', etc?

Comment: This can be easily done with a script in perl/python for example. If you provide more details regarding the logic for data replacement/insertion it would be easier to provide some guidelines.

Comment: @OrenD Perl, Python, Ruby, JavaScript, PHP, pretty much anything under the sun can read and write CSV.

Comment: Hi Gary, Yep its one continuous line, however line breaks are there ';'.Its an extract from a database. In this example, the EU size2 (Insert) needs updating to 34 to match the EU size1 (32).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load into Excel and do a formula on the insert column that looks at the 11th column and based on that sets it's value.  Set your list separator character to a semi-colon in the regional settings first.